# 'I called you yesterday' or 'I was calling you yesterday'?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

Which one of these sentences are more accurate in this specific context and what the differences between both of them are?

> A: I was calling you yesterday about the flat you are offering
>
> B: I called you yesterday about the flat you are offering..

I  went with B option when writing a message.. but not completely sure about it
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to ELL. For future reference, it might be helpful to include more details, like whether your examples are from real or from a textbook, and your thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Option B

> I called you yesterday about the flat you are offering ...

Is simple and unambiguous, it has a sense of completion coming from **called you**.

If you tried to call but perhaps instead spoke to a different person

> I called yesterday about the flat you are offering, but you were not available.

Again there is clear sense of completion.

> I was calling you yesterday about the flat you are offering

This has a feeling that the call was in some way incomplete, there's an implication that something happened while I was calling

> I was calling you yesterday about the flat you are offering, but our conversation was cut short by ...

Answer (score 1):

Without exact context, we can say which is best, but, the main difference:

> A: I was calling you yesterday about the flat you are offering

Means you called several times over the course of the day.

> B: I called you yesterday about the flat you are offering..

Means you called once, maybe twice, at some point in the day.

Comment: Well I actually called only once.. so my point was right.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> I called you yesterday about the flat you are offering.

You either called once yesterday, or less likely called multiple times and didn't need to call anymore.  "Called you yesterday" is a "finished" action.

> I was calling you yesterday about the flat you are offering

You called multiple times (or maybe a single really long call), but still needed to call today for whatever reason. There's an implied period of time over which multiple calls occurred, and you are including "now" in that time.

Contrast with:

> I had been calling you yesterday about the flat you are offering.

You called multiple times, there's an implied period of time over which multiple calls occurred, but "now" is not part of that time.